# Jenkins Pipeline - ReadProperties from a remote git url

Tags: jenkins, properties

I have a properties file located in a git project. While building a separate project, I want to read this property file to extract some common configuration.

readProperties only allows to load files from the current workspace.

How can I read a properties file from a different git project in the pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clone repo/just download properties file:

```
node() {

    stage("Clone repo") {
        git url: "https://github.com/ozlevka/go-envinronment.git"
        //fileDownloadOperation url: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ozlevka/go-envinronment/master/bbb.properties"
    }

    stage("Read properies") 
    {
        def props = readProperties  file: './bbb.properties'
        for (def key in props.keySet())
        {
            println "key = ${key}, value = ${props[key]}"
        }
    }
}
```

[Documentation for readProperties](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readproperties-read-properties-from-files-in-the-workspace-or-text), [git](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/git/#git-git) and for [fileDownloadOperation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/file-operations/#fileoperations-file-operations)